# What are the required things to retrieve the data from google analytics using client id and client secret

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can generated the client id and client secret from the google developer window.
Also i created c# program to fetch the data from google analytics api with generated client id and client secret.

Through c# program i can fetch the data successfully.
But for first time it asks me to login with my gmail account like below image and I clicked allow. 
[Gmail login page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCGkt.png)
[Allow deny page to access gmail data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCM4.png)

After clicking allow I can retrieve the data.
I tried to use same c# application in another system.
There i have to login for another time and clicked allow for the given gmail account.
My question

Is Gmail username and password is necessary to retrieve the data from the google analytics using client id and client secret ?
The above login and allow pages appear only for first time, then it retrieves the data.

Also I tried with service account.
There I  used only json file to retrive the data.
There I cannot get login and allow page to retrieve the data.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Google Analytics is an authenticated API which requires the use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). The data belongs to a user, and the user has to authorize your application to to have access their data. A service account is a fake user (has an email address and everything) you can add this service account to an Analytics View and then with the json (or p12 file) you will be able to access the data in that view. The things need to access Analytics data with a client Id and client secret == an **Analytics account user**